# Converting Dictionary Value to CGFloat in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert a value stored in a Dictionary to a CGFloat

```
let dict:Dictionary <String, Any> = ["num": 100]
let cgf = CGFloat(d["num"] as Double)

let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(cgf,200,10,10)
```

This causes a run time error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are experimenting is because in Swift `Double`, `Float`, `Int`, etc, are not objects, but structs. You have to cast the value as a `NSNumber` and then get the `floatValue` from there. Something like this:

```
let dict:Dictionary <String, Any> = ["num": 100]
let cgf = dict["num"] as? NSNumber
NSLog("Float: %f", cgf!.floatValue)

let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(cgf!.floatValue),200,10,10)
```

**EDIT**

if you are 100 percent the dictionary holds a value for the key then just do:

```
let cgf = dict["num"] as NSNumber

let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(cgf.floatValue),200,10,10)
```

Comment: `Double`, `Float`, `Int` are defined as structures, I think they are objects.

Comment: Is there any reason why you forced this into an Optional? If I could guarantee that the Dictionary always had a number value under `num` could I safely do away with the Optional?

Comment: @Swipesight you're right, they are structs no literals, but that doesn't mean they are objects, they're structs ;) and for that reason you can't downcast directly

Comment: @Jimmery if you can guarantee the dictionary will always contain the value there is no need to make it optional

Answer (score 1):

“Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/tw/jEUH0.l

`Any` can't force downcast to `Double`.
Your dictionary can contain objects of any type, force downcast will not always succeed.